# SharePoint meta data colum in toplevel site

Tags: sharepoint-2010

In SharePoint is it possible to create a metadata column in Top Level Site which can be used in lists and libraries of sub sites. 
For example I am having a top level site called  Projects, I want to define a metadata column in the top level site called ProjectId. At the time of creating sub site I want to assign a value like 1001 to the ProjectId metadata for the subsite.

Answer (score 0):

> In SharePoint is it possible to create a metadata column in Top Level
>   Site which can be used in lists and libraries of sub sites.

Yes, it is. Create the column in your top level site and it will be available throughout the site collection.

> At the time of creating sub site I want to assign a value like 1001 to
>   the ProjectId metadata for the subsite.

Not so sure you can do that. The subsite doesn't have it's "own" copy of the site column you defined above. You may be able to use functionality like 'Location Based Defaults' on document libraries to 'override' the default value.